# Existe algo equivalente a classe DOMdocument do php para javascript ou angularjs?

Tags: php, javascript, angularjs

**Situação:**
Dado a url, precisaria de todas as classes usadas dentro da página.

Há um método da classe `DomDocument` que eu precisaria utilizar (`->loadHTMLFile($url)`).

Existe algo equivalente a esta classe para `javascript` ou `angularjs`?

- Precisava carregar uma `url` e depois fazer uma busca pelas tags (gostaria de pegar apenas as classes)

  ```
  $dom = new DOMDocument;
  $dom->loadHTMLFile('https://www.youtube.com/'); // a url vai aqui
  $elements = $doc->getElementsByTagName('input');

  foreach($elements as $el){
      //retorna todas as classes referente aos inputs
      echo $el->getAttribute('class')."\n";
  }
  ```

Em javascript é possível fazer apenas uma busca pela página atual (aonde o script está inserido), por exemplo:

- Queria fazer dado uma `url` e dai a busca pelas `classes`

  ```
  var $elements = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
  var show = "";
  for(var i = 0; i < $elements.length; i++){
      var tagClass = $elements[i].getAttribute('class');
      if( tagClass !== null){
          show += tagClass ;
      }
  }
  alert(show);
  ```

Comment: Está querendo usar o Javascript para acessar uma página externa? Tem que ver a questão do CORS, em alguns sites você não consegue fazer requisições via Javascript. Talvez o PHP seja a melhor opção nesse caso. Agora, se estiver falando de consultar um HTML que você mesmo está manipulando em sua página, dá sim pra fazer.

Comment: Que informação você quer pegar do Youtube, existem alternativas. Ou pode fazer um "web proxy" com php (com cache de preferencia) mesmo e depois repassar com Ajax para o Javascript.

Comment: O xpath não serviria neste contexto ?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento posso estar errado, mas parece que ele quer pegar pela classe e o domDocument não tem, aí o xpath resolve, creio ser por isso ele querer usar js... posso estar errado...

Comment: @MagicHat o problema realmente é o "download", pegar as tags seria o passo "2".